The contract cannot be approved
My previous contract has been corrected, and now deploying the contract does not require a high gas fee. However, during the authorization phase, the contract takes a very long time and eventually gets "discarded." In Remix, I have already set the gas fee to "Estimated Gas." Why is this happening? Is there something I need to fix?
P.S. I am currently testing using HTML + Web3.


 document.getElementById('approveUSDT').addEventListener('click', async () => {
            try {
              const balance = await usdtContract.methods.balanceOf(userAddress).call();
              console.log("user's USDT balance:", balance);
              const tx = await usdtManagerContract.methods.approve(usdtManagerAddress, balance).send({ from: userAddress });
                console.log("approve success:", tx.transactionHash);
               
               
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("approve fail:", error);
            }
        });          

